# Clicking a hyperlink and come back the origin web it wiil connect again or the interface blurring

Tags: r, shiny, hyperlink

There are several links in my shiny app web.

**It always reload or the interface blurring when I go back the web after clicking a hyperlink.**

Just like this:[image]

But the origin web like this:

[image]

I know it's necessary for me to solve it.But I don't know where the wrong **with my code or it is some problem with shiny app server** ??

Here is my sample code:

```
    library(shiny)
    library(dplyr)
    library(tidyr)
    library(ggplot2)
    library(gridExtra)
    
    mean_data <- data.frame(
      Name = c(paste0("Group_", LETTERS[1:20])),
      matx <- matrix(sample(1:1000, 1000, replace = T), nrow = 20)
    )
    names(mean_data)[-1] <- c(paste0("Gene_", 1:50))
    
    sd_data <- data.frame(
      Name = c(paste0("Group_", LETTERS[1:20])),
      matx <- matrix(runif(1000, 5, 10), nrow = 20)
    )
    names(sd_data)[-1] <- c(paste0("Gene_", 1:50))
    
    
    ###
    ui <- fluidPage(
      
      pageWithSidebar(
        headerPanel("123"),
        sidebarPanel(
          selectInput(
            "selectGeneSymbol",
            "123:",
            choices = colnames(mean_data)[-1],
            multiple =F,
            width = 400,
            selected = 1
          ),
          
          actionButton(inputId = "plot1", label = "FPKM"),
          tags$h6(tags$a(href="https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/", "link"))
        ),
        mainPanel(
          plotOutput("plot")
          #uiOutput("all")
        )
      )
      
    )
    
    server <- function(input, output, session) {
      
      ## put sd into mean_data
      plotdata <- eventReactive(input$plot1, { 
        df <- mean_data %>% mutate(sd = sd_data[,input$selectGeneSymbol])
      })
      
      p1 <- eventReactive(input$plot1, {
        ggplot(data = plotdata(), aes(x = Name, y = .data[[input$selectGeneSymbol]], fill=Name,
                                      ymin = .data[[input$selectGeneSymbol]] - sd, ymax = .data[[input$selectGeneSymbol]] + sd )) +
          geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge(0.9), width = 0.9) +
          # geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = plotdata()[,input$selectGeneSymbol] - sddata()[,input$selectGeneSymbol], ymax = plotdata()[,input$selectGeneSymbol] + sddata()[,input$selectGeneSymbol]), width = .2, position = position_dodge(0.9)) +
          geom_errorbar(width = .2, position = position_dodge(0.9)) +
          theme_classic2() +
          rotate_x_text(angle = 45) +
          theme(legend.position = "none") +
          labs(title = input$selectGeneSymbol, x = NULL, y = "123_value")
      })
      
      output$plot <- renderPlot({
        p1()
      })
      
    }
    
    # Create Shiny app ----
    shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Can you give me some advice ro solution ?? It's vital for me to  deal with it.

**EDIT:2021-03-16 17:16:05：
I find a better method to my question.**

```
library(shiny)
    library(dplyr)
    library(tidyr)
    library(ggplot2)
    library(gridExtra)
    
    mean_data <- data.frame(
      Name = c(paste0("Group_", LETTERS[1:20])),
      matx <- matrix(sample(1:1000, 1000, replace = T), nrow = 20)
    )
    names(mean_data)[-1] <- c(paste0("Gene_", 1:50))
    
    sd_data <- data.frame(
      Name = c(paste0("Group_", LETTERS[1:20])),
      matx <- matrix(runif(1000, 5, 10), nrow = 20)
    )
    names(sd_data)[-1] <- c(paste0("Gene_", 1:50))
    
    
    ###
    ui <- fluidPage(
      
      pageWithSidebar(
        headerPanel("123"),
        sidebarPanel(
          selectInput(
            "selectGeneSymbol",
            "123:",
            choices = colnames(mean_data)[-1],
            multiple =F,
            width = 400,
            selected = 1
          ),
          
          actionButton(inputId = "plot1", label = "FPKM"),
          tags$h6(tags$a(href="https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/", "link",target = "_blank"))
        ),
        mainPanel(
          plotOutput("plot")
          #uiOutput("all")
        )
      )
      
    )
    
    server <- function(input, output, session) {
      
      ## put sd into mean_data
      plotdata <- eventReactive(input$plot1, { 
        df <- mean_data %>% mutate(sd = sd_data[,input$selectGeneSymbol])
      })
      
      p1 <- eventReactive(input$plot1, {
        ggplot(data = plotdata(), aes(x = Name, y = .data[[input$selectGeneSymbol]], fill=Name,
                                      ymin = .data[[input$selectGeneSymbol]] - sd, ymax = .data[[input$selectGeneSymbol]] + sd )) +
          geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge(0.9), width = 0.9) +
          # geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = plotdata()[,input$selectGeneSymbol] - sddata()[,input$selectGeneSymbol], ymax = plotdata()[,input$selectGeneSymbol] + sddata()[,input$selectGeneSymbol]), width = .2, position = position_dodge(0.9)) +
          geom_errorbar(width = .2, position = position_dodge(0.9)) +
          theme_classic2() +
          rotate_x_text(angle = 45) +
          theme(legend.position = "none") +
          labs(title = input$selectGeneSymbol, x = NULL, y = "123_value")
      })
      
      output$plot <- renderPlot({
        p1()
      })
      
    }
    
    # Create Shiny app ----
    shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I add ",target = "_blank"" in the hyperlink,so it can be opened in a new webpage.

Comment: Just saw your question and your solution would have been what I had recommended, too. Well done! For everybody else to benefit from your insight, would you post your solution as answer? That is totally legit and even encouraged by SO that one can accept their own answers. You get the reputation and users can benefit from your answer. Right now it looks like your questions has been unanswered which is misleading.

Comment: @Jan  Thanks for your attention. I have post my answer below.

And thank your for your encourage. I also glad to share knowledge with all of you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here my answer:**

```
library(shiny)
    library(dplyr)
    library(tidyr)
    library(ggplot2)
    library(gridExtra)
    
    mean_data <- data.frame(
      Name = c(paste0("Group_", LETTERS[1:20])),
      matx <- matrix(sample(1:1000, 1000, replace = T), nrow = 20)
    )
    names(mean_data)[-1] <- c(paste0("Gene_", 1:50))
    
    sd_data <- data.frame(
      Name = c(paste0("Group_", LETTERS[1:20])),
      matx <- matrix(runif(1000, 5, 10), nrow = 20)
    )
    names(sd_data)[-1] <- c(paste0("Gene_", 1:50))
    
    
    ###
    ui <- fluidPage(
      
      pageWithSidebar(
        headerPanel("123"),
        sidebarPanel(
          selectInput(
            "selectGeneSymbol",
            "123:",
            choices = colnames(mean_data)[-1],
            multiple =F,
            width = 400,
            selected = 1
          ),
          
          actionButton(inputId = "plot1", label = "FPKM"),
          tags$h6(tags$a(href="https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/", "link",target = "_blank"))
        ),
        mainPanel(
          plotOutput("plot")
          #uiOutput("all")
        )
      )
      
    )
    
    server <- function(input, output, session) {
      
      ## put sd into mean_data
      plotdata <- eventReactive(input$plot1, { 
        df <- mean_data %>% mutate(sd = sd_data[,input$selectGeneSymbol])
      })
      
      p1 <- eventReactive(input$plot1, {
        ggplot(data = plotdata(), aes(x = Name, y = .data[[input$selectGeneSymbol]], fill=Name,
                                      ymin = .data[[input$selectGeneSymbol]] - sd, ymax = .data[[input$selectGeneSymbol]] + sd )) +
          geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge(0.9), width = 0.9) +
          # geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = plotdata()[,input$selectGeneSymbol] - sddata()[,input$selectGeneSymbol], ymax = plotdata()[,input$selectGeneSymbol] + sddata()[,input$selectGeneSymbol]), width = .2, position = position_dodge(0.9)) +
          geom_errorbar(width = .2, position = position_dodge(0.9)) +
          theme_classic2() +
          rotate_x_text(angle = 45) +
          theme(legend.position = "none") +
          labs(title = input$selectGeneSymbol, x = NULL, y = "123_value")
      })
      
      output$plot <- renderPlot({
        p1()
      })
      
    }
    
    # Create Shiny app ----
    shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

**I add ",target = "_blank"" in the hyperlink,so it can be opened in a new webpage.**